# XSLTForms: Convert Text to HTML - add to DOM - deal with bad input?

Tags: javascript, html, xslt, xforms, xsltforms

Is there some way I can get [XSLTForms](http://www.agencexml.com/xsltforms) to convert CDATA into HTML nodes which can then output to the DOM?

Any tips appreciated - one requirement - the data cannot be guaranteed to be valid HTML, so the solution will need to fall-back gracefully (and just display the text as-is - which is what I'm currently doing).

**XFORM:**

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="xsltforms/xsltforms.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<?xsltforms-options debug="no"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
      xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
      >
<head>

<xf:model>
    <xf:instance src="data.xml"/>
</xf:model>

</head>
<body>

<h1> What's on Tonight </h1>

<xf:repeat ref="records/record">
    <details>
        <summary>
            <xf:output ref="title"/>
        </summary>
        <p>
            <xf:output ref="description"/>
        </p>
    </details>
</xf:repeat>

</body>
</html>
```

**DATA:**

```
<data xmlns="">
    <records>
        <record>
            <title><![CDATA[Macbeth]]></title>
            <description><![CDATA[A <b>bold</b> interpretation of the classic play]]></description>
        </record>
        <record>
            <title><![CDATA[Malformed]]></title>
            <description><![CDATA[Distopian Sci-Fi Thriller, set in a post-XML world where elements are left <unclosed>]]></description>
        </record>
    </records>
</data>
```

**Current output:**

[image: current output]

**Desired output:**

[image: Desired output]

Comment: If there is an xsltforms version or processor that supports XPath 3.1/XSLT 3.0 then you can use the `parse-xml-fragment` function on each `description` element node.

Comment: I didn't notice the `Distopian Sci-Fi Thriller, set in a post-XML world where elements are left <unclosed>` on the first read, in XSLT 3 you might be able to handle that using `xsl:try/xsl:catch` but I have no idea whether you can use that from xsltforms (does it allow adding XSLT 2 o3 `xsl:function`s so that you could use the `xsl:try/xsl:catch` in the function body?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `output/@ref`, you should use `output/@value` and `output/@mediatype`:

```html
<details>
    <summary>
        <xf:output value="title"/>
    </summary>
    <p>
        <xf:output value="description" mediatype="text/html"/>
    </p>
</details>
```

Comment: Merci beaucoup ! Works.

Comment: I didn't try yet with *bad* HTML - but my understanding is, it won't break XSLTForms rendering - although of course my page might not look very good.

Comment: XSLTForms Javascript part is using .innerHTML to render the calculated value.

Comment: Thanks again - and I tried with bad HTML - and all was well with XSLTForms. (I just wasn't sure whether I had to make sure my *output* was properly formed XML, to prevent a 'cliff-edge' failure - i.e. nothing rendering at all)

Comment: Sorry to wake up this thread again - I have switched from 'ref' to 'output' (works) - but now trying 'bind' - which shows output as text again. Is it just fundamentally the way it has to be for 'bind' and 'ref'? (I would like to use 'bind' for other reasons - keeping UI and model separate). Thanks again.

Comment: Actually - don't worry - I have a technique that will work for me. I just have to keep one special temporary instance - which I used a calculate bind with. And then just for this special ("scratchpad"/"temp"/"state") model/instance - I will use 'ref' not value. My main data-models will still use 'bind' though.